# 404 Not Found error when posting to JSP file in a maven web project

Tags: java, jquery, maven, jsp, servlets

I'm new to Java. I'm working on a maven web application and can't seem to POST data from my index file to another JSP File. It seems to work fine when I imitate this in a Java Web Application. I'm using NetBeans.

Here's how my files are arranged:

[File Arrangement Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0id7.jpg)

Here's the jQuery code inside index.jsp:

```
$("#edit-save-btn").on('click', function () {
        $.post('/editSupplier', $("#supplier-info-edit").serialize(), function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            var $id = $("#editSupplierId").val();
            $row = $("demo-id [data-id=" + $id + "]");
            $row.find('input[data-title=name]').html($("#name").val());
            $row.find('input[data-title=contact]').html($("#contact").val());
            $row.find('input[data-title=email]').html($("#email").val());
            $row.find('input[data-title=status]').html($("#status").val());
            $("#edit").modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

This is what I've written in editSupplier.jsp (destination):

```
if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
    SupplierDAO SupplierDAO = new SupplierDAOImpl();
    Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
    supplier.setName(request.getParameter("sname"));
    supplier.setContact(request.getParameter("scontact"));
    supplier.setEmail(request.getParameter("semail"));
    supplier.setStatus(request.getParameter("sstatus") != null);
    String id = request.getParameter("sid");
    supplier.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    SupplierDAO.update(supplier);
    response.sendRedirect("/index");
}
```

In my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Whenever I click the "Update" button in my modal, it should post the input form data to editSupplier.jsp and then redirect me to index.jsp, but I get this:
[Error Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv8ug.jpg)

Please help, I've been pulling my hair out.

Edit: I have this in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

Comment: try with out '../' so your ;ink should be `editSupplier.jsp` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have something like this in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` :

```
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Don't forget your jsp are also servlets and need a mapping to by resolved. In this example, only jsp under `/WEB-INF/views` are mapped and the `server` folder is not public.

I suggest you to move your `server` folder under `views` folder and then replace your `../server/editSupplier.jsp` by a `server/editSupplier.jsp` relative url.

Comment: Wow, you're a wizard. Yes, I do have something like that in my dispatcher-servlet.xml: <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>


I moved "editSupplier.jsp" to the "views" folder (same folder as index.jsp) and also changed the URLs accordingly to their respective destinations. But I still get the same 404 Error saying they could not locate the editSupplier.jsp folder. I didn't make changes to the dispatcher-servlet.xml file. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Oh nevermind, it seems I had missed a spot when replacing the URLs and now it's working fine. Thanks a lot guy!